# Installing Ubuntu and BackTrack in VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, backtrack

I'm going to install both Ubuntu and BackTrack in VMWare Workstation 8.

If I were to install these on my HD, I'd have to make a partition for each. Is this the same procedure for installing these OS's in VMWare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VMWare you create two virtual machines each with it's own Virtual Hard Disk (The virtual hard disks are just files that reside on a partition in the host machine's HD).